# Javascript: add body ID based on part of search results url

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I know just enough JS to get in trouble so please bear with me :)

I am using the WP-Properties WordPress plugin.  When searching for properties it gives all results in a common search results page.  I need to theme the search results page based on part of the search string so I need a body id.

Example of a search result url:

http://website.com/property/?wpp_search[pagination]=off&wpp_search[property_type]=oasis_park&wpp_search[lot_location]=Oceano+Lot&wpp_search[availability]=-1&wpp_search[phase]=-1&wpp_search[price][min]=-1

The part I want is what comes after: "wpp_search[property_type]"

In the above case it would be "oasis_park"

And this would then create a body tag of:  `<body id="oasis_park">`

I tried to tweak the following code to get the specific part then have it write to the body tag but I can't get it to work in my situation: [remove a part of a URL argument string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799579/remove-a-part-of-a-url-argument-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

This will only work for this specific url, as you have not provided a general pattern for each url from which you will need to extract a substring:

```
var myString = "http://website.com/property/?wpp_search[pagination]=off&wpp_search[property_type]=oasis_park&wpp_search[lot_location]=Oceano+Lot&wpp_search[availability]=-1&wpp_search[phase]=-1&wpp_search[price][min]=-1";

var myVar = myString.slice(myString.indexOf("&") + 27, myString.indexOf("k"));
```

After you have identified a general pattern in every url you wish to check, you will then have to use a combination of substr(), slice() and indexOf() to get the substring you want.

Then, try

```
document.body.id = myVar;
```

or assign an id to `body` (e.g. "myID") then try this:

```
document.getElementById('myID').id = myVar;
```

Comment: The above will only put the `id=""` into the body tag. 

Additionally, the url is dynamic so it will change based on what is being searched for, but every one will have the property_type as part of it.

Comment: Can you please do me a favor and alert myVar in your function....what is alerted? Also, does every url fit a certain pattern similar to the url above?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to do the alert.  Can you tell me what to add to the script please?

Comment: add this line to your function, where myVar is your variable name in your function that corresponds to the myVar I used in my answer above: alert(myVar);

Comment: By the way, what event gets/displays the result url? An onclick? onload? other? Just remember, without an "event", the function will not be called unless it is an anonymous function (but not sure if you have any anonymous functions)

Comment: The alert only brings up a box with no information.  I didn't know there had to be an event... like I said, I'm a JS newbie :)  I added it using WP enqueue menthod so the script loads in the foot on page load.

Comment: OK...I have updated my answer...the indexOf had to be a single character....my bad. Try alerting myVar in your function using the amended code above. However, you will need to find a general pattern which fits each url. The methods I have provided above can serve as a general template...hope this helps.

Comment: If every url has the string property_type also look up the javascript function called match() and use something such as x.match(/property_type/)...this may also help